# In a plot, show in italic name passed as an element of a vector

Tags: r, plot, legend, italics

I have a vector of characters:

```
x <- c("species1", "species2", "species3")
```

I would like to add each of these elements in a plot, as a legend, for instance, like this:

```
legend("topleft", x[1], bty="n")
```

But here comes my problem: it needs to be in italic.

What I do is to try this:

```
legend("topright",expression(italic(x[1])), bty="n")
```

However, instead of getting it in italics the value in `x[1]` (in this case: `"species1"`), what I get in italics is the `"x[1]"` itself!

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: works fine for me. Can you make a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substitute` to swap out variables in an expression. This should work

```
legend("topright",legend=substitute(italic(x), list(x=x[1])), bty="n")
```